# get the actual value of the human-readable name from choices in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I made this model:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(
        ('sat', "Saturday"),
        ('sun', "Sunday"),
        ('mon', "Monday"),
        ('tue', "Tuesday"),
        ('wed', "Wednesday"),
        ('thu', "Thursday"),
        ('fri', "Friday"),
    ), null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True)
```

and when I want to get objects I can only access the human-readable name of choices.
how can I get an object by human-readable name?
I tried this but got an error:

```
Days.objects.get(name='saturday')
```

Comment: did you tried `Days.objects.get(name='sat')`

Comment: @webbyfox I don't want to use the actual value of choices. I want to get objects using human-readable value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ain't pretty, but you could reverse lookup via the models meta attribute:

```
class Days(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=(
            ('sat', "Saturday"),
            ('sun', "Sunday"),
            ('mon', "Monday"),
            ('tue', "Tuesday"),
            ('wed', "Wednesday"),
            ('thu', "Thursday"),
            ('fri', "Friday"),
        ), null=False, blank=False, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def human_name_to_choice(cls, human_readable_str):
        return {b: a for a, b in cls._meta.get_field('name').choices}.get(human_readable_str, 'NUL')

# ...

Days.objects.get(name=Days.human_name_to_choice('Saturday'))
```

You can modify it to be case insensitive (so that it would work in your example)

But be careful:

- Human readable strings must not be unique!
- If the human readable string can not be found in the choices, it returns a dummy ('NUL') - but this could be added at a later time and lead to confusion

Answer (score 8):

in your case: `instance.get_name_display()`

Django docs: [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)